# I am using Angular js1 .When i use angular select box ng-click is not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How to i use select box with ng-click function. i tried but this is not working my side .if any alternative share the code.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = ["john", "Aplle", "Ravi"];
    
    $scope.clicked**=function(){
    alert("hello");
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select>
<option ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="clicked()">{{item}}</option>
</select>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event` directive on `options` tag of `select` would never. You should use `ng-change` on select element rather.

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem"  ng-change="clicked()">
  <option ng-repeat="item in items" ng-value="item.value">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

Though the above is not correct way to solve your issue, you should use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat`

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" 
   ng-options="item for item in items"
   ng-change="clicked(item)">
</select>
```

Comment: @periyasamy you could accept answer. it if works for you, Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for answer this Question @pankaj Parkar. This is working commonly,but when i use and select ng-change="clicked(item)" this is clicked function can't working properly.if send 2 data click function.this ng-change is can't call properly ( not work similar to ng-click  ).how to i caal the function?

Comment: @periyasamy it should work, you tried `ng-options` which I suggested in second part of answer?

Comment: The Second part Work.but when i pass the value ng-change="clicked(item)"  can't get from console.the value is undefined.how i send value ng-change from controller.

Comment: Will create a plunkr for you later.

Comment: When i am using ng-if inside the select box.this is not working!.How to i use ng-if inside the select box? example `<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-if="Some Condition"
   ng-options="item for item in items"
   ng-change="clicked(item)">
</select>`

Comment: @periyasamy brother, please don't extend context of question, you should ask another question for different question..

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `ng-click` but it must be in the select:

```
<select ng-click="clicked()">
  <option ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: putting `ng-click="clicked()"` on select would not provide expected behaviour as it will get called as soon as you click on select, whether `ng-change` will behave as expected when option gets change?